# MANUSEIO DO EXPLORER ATRAVÉS DE VBA

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Bom dia, estou começando a trabalhar com o VBA então minha dúvida pode ser bem básica, mas meu problema é o seguinte: 
Quando eu executo o código (que está abaixo) a parece um alerta de erro na linha do 'For each'

> "Erro em tempo de execução '438'.    Objeto não aceita esta
>   propriedade ou método"

O código está análogo a outro que peguei de um amigo, apenas fazendo as mudanças pertinentes e o dele está funcionando.

```
Sub TesteBusca()

Dim ie As Object
Dim sWindows As Object
Dim sJanelas As Object
Dim sDados As String


Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.navigate "http://sdro.ons.org.br/SDRO/DIARIO/index.htm"
ie.Visible = True

    Do Until (ie.readyState = 4 And Not ie.Busy)
        DoEvents
    Loop

i = 1
For Each link In ie.document.getElementByTagName("a")

    If Mid(link.href, 8, 22) = "EnergiaNaturalAfluente" Then
    i = i + 1

       With iefat
           .Visible = bMostrarNavegador
           .navigate link.href
       End With

       Do Until (iefat.readyState = 4 And Not iefat.Busy)
         DoEvents
       Loop
    link.Click
    If i = 2 Then Exit For
    End If

Next link


End Sub
```

Agradeço desde já,
Abs.

Comment: O do seu amigo está no mesmo site? Pois neste da ons, creio que possui um iframe... Então o código do DOM mudaria.

Comment: Não, o site que ele usou foi este "http://sys.sigetplus.com.br/cobranca/transmitter/1191/invoices?agent=5111". Como eu devo fazer para abrir o link, então?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Código

Você pode realizar isto com este código:

```
'Declara função Sleep
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If

Sub TesteBusca()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim sWindows As Object
    Dim sJanelas As Object
    Dim sDados As String
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.navigate "http://sdro.ons.org.br/SDRO/DIARIO/index.htm"
    IE.Visible = True

    EsperaIE IE, 2000

    'Debug.Print IE.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(1).contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("a").innerText
    i = 1
    For Each link In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(1).contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("a")
    'Debug.Print EXTRAIRELEMENTO(link.href, 8, "/")
        If EXTRAIRELEMENTO(link.href, 8, "/") = "21_EnergiaNaturalAfluente.html" Then
            i = i + 1


            link.Click
             EsperaIE IE, 2000
            If i = 2 Then Exit For
        End If

    Next link   
End Sub

Public Sub EsperaIE(IE As Object, Optional time As Long = 250)
'Código de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808000/run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set
Dim i As Long
Do
    Sleep time
    Debug.Print CStr(i) & vbTab & "Ready: " & CStr(IE.READYSTATE = 4) & _
                vbCrLf & vbTab & "Busy: " & CStr(IE.Busy)
    i = i + 1
Loop Until IE.READYSTATE = 4 Or Not IE.Busy
End Sub

Function EXTRAIRELEMENTO(Txt As String, n, Separator As String) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    EXTRAIRELEMENTO = Split(Application.Trim(Mid(Txt, 1)), Separator)(n - 1)
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ' error handling code
    MsgBox "Erro, veriique os dados de entrada."
    EXTRAIRELEMENTO = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

## Explicação

#### Extrair Elemento

A Função Definida pelo Usuário (*UDF - User Defined Function*) de extrair elemento é declarada para extrair os elementos de uma string separados por um separador, neste exemplo "/", em que cada elemento possui um index.

Esta utiliza a função [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) para dividir a string em vários elementos a partir de um separador.

E a função `Trim` é usada para evitar erros quando o espaço é utilizado como separador, pois esta função retira os espaços do início e fim da string.

Exemplo: `EXTRAIRELEMENTO("http://sdro.ons.org.br/SDRO/DIARIO/2018_03_15/Html/DIARIO_15-03-2018.xlsx", 1, "/")` retorna o valor `http:`

Outro Exemplo:
`EXTRAIRELEMENTO("http://sdro.ons.org.br/SDRO/DIARIO/2018_03_15/Html/DIARIO_15-03-2018.xlsx", 2, "/")` retorna o valor `` ou vazio

Outro:

`EXTRAIRELEMENTO("http://sdro.ons.org.br/SDRO/DIARIO/2018_03_15/Html/DIARIO_15-03-2018.xlsx", 3, "/")` retorna o valor `sdro.ons.org.br`

Uma função muito útil, que pode ser aplicada para extrair elementos de Strings com separadores, como links, diretórios, códigos de produto, datas,  entre outros.

#### Espera IE

Normalmente eu utilizo uma função do SOen para realizar a função de esperar um tempo para a página ser carregada completamente, somente `While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: Wend` pode não ser suficiente.

Então ao invés de `While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: Wend` Você chama a função `EsperaIE` e escolhe o tempo de espera em ms. Exemplo: `EsperaIE IE, 5000`

#### Código principal

Como o site da ONS possui uma hierarquia com iFrames e não somente o HTML "puro". Você precisa procurar pela tag "a" com: `IE.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(1).contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("a")`, em que o index da frame é **(1)**, pois o index (0) é do topo da página.

> OBS.: Não esqueça de habilitar as referências: Microsoft HTML Object Library e Microsoft Internet Controls.

Em **Ferramentas** > **Referências...**

[image: Habilitar as Referências]

Comment: Daniel, muito obrigado pela ajuda!! Só não consegui entender direito a parte o Extrair Elemento o que quer dizar "Split(Application.Trim(Mid(Txt, 1)), Separator)(n - 1)". 
E tentei executar o código e aparece "Erro de compilação: o tipo definido pelo usuário não foi definido" e destaca o "doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument". O que devo fazer?

Comment: @LeandroLazari Editei a resposta, você precisa habilitar a referência MS HTML Object Library. E isto é uma função definida pelo usuário, ou seja, uma função customizada criada pelo usuário e não nativa do Excel. Ela foi criada para separar os elementos, onde os dados de entrada dela são Txt, Separator e n. Muitas funções podem ser encontradas na internet e muitas vezes você não precisa entendê-las por complexa (é bom saber o funcionamento), mas para economizar tempo, você pode somente saber os dados de entrada e quais valores/saídas a função retorna.

Comment: Muito bom! Parabéns pela resposta.

Comment: Entendi! Primeiramente obrigado! você está sendo de grande ajuda! Mas estou com outra dúvida, o meu próximo passo seria clicar no ícone que faz o download do arquivo xls. Tentei utilizar o mesmo argumento mas alterando o 'If' do 'For Each':

   For Each link In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(1).contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("a")
    'Debug.Print EXTRAIRELEMENTO(link.href, 8, "/")
        If link.getAttribute("scr") = "../img/exportxls.gif" Then
            i = i + 1

Mas não acontece nada. Se puder me ajudar mais uma vez...

Comment: @LeandroLazari Sugiro criar uma nova pergunta e quando algum usuário estiver livre irá respondê-lo.

Comment: Ok. Obrigado, Daniel!!