# Como manipular objetos do IE que não contenham um ID? VBA Access

Tags: vba

Boa tarde, não estou conseguindo manipular (inmputar valor) objetos (textbox) de uma página do IE, pois estes objetos não possuem ID.
Segue o código que estou utilizando

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim Ulogin As Boolean, ieForm
Dim NumProc As String: NumProc = Me.ComarcaProcesso
Dim Email As String: Email = "fulano@gmail.com"
Dim Senha As String: Senha = "123456"

 Set IE = New InternetExplorer
 Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

 'Abre o IE maximizado.
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.navigate "http://www.tjrs.jus.br/site/processos/tjrs_push/"
  apiShowWindow IE.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE

 'Espera até que a página esteja totalmente carregada.
 Do Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
 Loop

 'Nessa parte você deve conhecer a propriedade "name" dos elementos input do site que irá logar.
  IE.Document.all("email").innerText = Email
  IE.Document.all("senha").innerText = Senha

 'Nessa parte você deve informar o nome (propriedade name) do formulário a ser submetido.
  IE.Document.all("login").Click

    Do
    'Coloca o nome do campo usuário do form na página.
     IE.Document.all("input_num_themis").innerText = NumProc

     DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Este código não funciona porque está dentro de um iFrame. Tente automatizar por este site: [http://www.tjrs.jus.br/proc/sistema_push/](http://www.tjrs.jus.br/proc/sistema_push/)

Comment: Funcionou! Como eu faço para identificar esse caminho em outros sites?

Comment: Cada site tem suas peculiaridades... No caso deste do tjrs, eles possuíam este caminho dentro do código do iFrame. Mas geralmente não possuem, então você teria que descobrir a hierarquia do site e utilizar outro "tipo" de código. Como [neste exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/285054/75104), em que os links estão dentro de frames...

Comment: entendi. muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Se você inspecionar o elemento, perceberá que os campos que você quer editar estão dentro de um `iframe`, cuja fonte é `/proc/sistema_push/`. Portanto, para referenciar os campos de e-mail e senha, você precisa antes referenciar o `iframe`. Para buscar o iframe, vamos iterar os iframes da página, e comparar a URL. Note que o atributo `src` contém um caminho relativo, mas o valor retornado pelo atributo `URL`da `iframe` é absoluto, por isso vamos acrescentar o domínio do site do Tribunal no termo de comparação.

Só vou adicionar uma variável (Cont) e um bloco de instrução `for`.

Vamos lá:

```
Sub MacacoLoko()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim docHTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim Ulogin As Boolean, ieForm
    Dim NumProc As String: NumProc = Me.ComarcaProcesso
    Dim Email As String: Email = "fulano@gmail.com"
    Dim Senha As String: Senha = "123456"
    Dim Cont As Variant 'Vai ser o marcador para iterar as iframes em busca da correta (embora esse site só tenha uma, outros sites de tribunais podem ter mais, ou o site pode ser reformulado)

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    'Abre o IE maximizado.
     IE.Visible = True
     IE.navigate "http://www.tjrs.jus.br/site/processos/tjrs_push/"
     apiShowWindow IE.Hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE

    'Espera até que a página esteja totalmente carregada.
    Do Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    'Itera as iframes, buscando a correta (no nosso caso, procuraremos pelo atributo "src" da tag "iframe".
    For Each Cont In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")
       If Cont.src = "http://www.tjrs.jus.br/proc/sistema_push/" Then Set docHTML = Cont 'Atribuímos docHTML à iframe correta. Importante: O atributo "src" no HTML da página está em caminho relativo, mas a URL da frame tem que ser buscada com a URL completa.
    Next Cont

    'Nessa parte você deve conhecer a propriedade "name" dos elementos input do site que irá logar.
     docHTML.all("email").innerText = Email
     docHTML.all("senha").innerText = Senha

    'Nessa parte você deve informar o nome (propriedade name) do formulário a ser submetido.
     IE.Document.all("login").Click

   'Daqui pra frente eu não testei; talvez seja necessário reatribuir o "dochtml", caso o número do processo esteja dentro de outra iframe, mas você já entendeu como se faz isso.
   Do
   'Coloca o nome do campo usuário do form na página.
    IE.Document.all("input_num_themis").innerText = NumProc

    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
   Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score -3):

\\vocÊ consegue acessar todos os dados do Iframe fácilmente.
É só você setar ele duas vezes no caso . Na verdade você seta ele e depois seta o documento inteiro com VBA..
Observe:
Set iframe = HTMLDoc.all("Nome do meu frame você inspeciona ele.")
Set iframe2 = iframe.contentDocument