# Preencher combobox na página WEB via VBA

Tags: html, microsoft-excel, vba

Estou tentando através do VBA no Excel, preencher um *combobox* em uma página de internet.

Mas, quando executo o código, aparece aquela mensagem de erro dizendo que **"o objeto não aceita esta propriedade ou método"**. A parte do código HTML da página da internet é este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Combobox que preciso preencher é do tipo "text", e vou inserir um CEP:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código está escrito assim:

```
IE.Document.getElementByName("zipcode").innertext = "13214661"
```

Já alterei, tentando usar o `document.all`, `document.GetElementByID`, `document.GetElementByClass`, etc. Enfim, mesmo não manjando de HTML, fiz algumas tentativas. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Sem toda a estrutura do HTML é difícil dizer, mas [pode estar dentro de um frame](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/285054/75104), ou há algum evento que precisa ser acionado, por exemplo [o evento onchange](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/288276/75104)

Answer (score 1):

Adicione um tempo utilizando **sleep** antes de tentar inserir o CEP.
 fora da funções, de preferencia no topo digite:

**Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)**

E dentro do código, acima da linha :
IE.Document.getElementByName("zipcode").innertext = "13214661"

coloque sleep 1000 'Tempo de 1 segundo

Por alguns motivos pode ter tentado procurar o elemento sem ter terminado de carregar a página.

Comment: Favor ler [como formatar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas)